# Query to fetch records in a join and with multiple filters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB as tableBJoin on tableBJoin.tableAId = tableA.id 
INNER JOIN tableC as tableCJoin on tableBJoin.tableCId = tableC.id 
INNER JOIN (
              SELECT tableBId,status, createdAt, type
              FROM  tableD 
              WHERE (tableBId, createdAt, type) IN (
                SELECT tableBId,max(createdAt), type
                FROM tableD   
                GROUP BY tableBId, type )) AS tableDVerification
              ON 
         
        tableBJoin.id= tableDVerification.tableBId
              AND (slug = 'foo' and status = 'pending') AND tableDVerification.type = 'cip';
```

This query the existing identities that matches with the filters in the WHERE clause. The tables structure is the following:

Table A:

```
id - tableBId - createdAt

1 - 4 - 2010-10-10
```

Table B:

```
id - tableCId - createdAt

4 - 3 - 2010-10-10
5 - 1 - 2010-10-10
```

Table C:

```
id - slug - createdAt

4 - foo - 2010-10-10
5 - biz - 2010-10-10
```

Table D:

```
id - tableBId - status - type - createdAt

1 - 4 - approved - cip -2010-10-10
2 - 5 - pending  - cip -2010-10-11
```

What I need to achieve now it's to add one more filter there. So for example. If I have an identity with records in the tableB associated with the slug `foo` and `biz`, if I add a filter like `slug = 'foo' and status = 'approved'  and slug = 'biz' and status = 'pending'`, the query should return the identity.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll get more help if you strip back the query so it's readable. For example replacing `"identity_manager"."identity"` with say `mgr`, shortening unnecessarily long names like `identityVerification` to say `id_ver`, removing all unnecessary `"` characters (which I think is all of them) and removing all parts of the query (ie most of the columns) not required to demonstrate the problem. Copy pasting your actual query into the question is lazy. Put some effort into making a simplified abstract version that clearly shows the problem and makes your question useful to more people.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Bohemian. I cleaned up the query. Is this something you can help?

Comment: Your query doesn't quite look correct, but if you want rows that have both conditions, you must join to the subquery twice - once for each condition. You can do this but still have the subquery run only once by using a [CTE via the `WITH` keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: I tried doing that but with two inner joins the record does not appear. Only if i use one join to the table D